# Unable to create database file on another desktop with build .exe file Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter desktop application and I want to create database file for local data storage.
I am using the following plugin to get path of directory for creating database file.
https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_windows

[Image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMp7A.png

Here is the screenshot of my code. I am printing the path where the database file will be located. When i run this app on my desktop it is working fine and create the database file also. But could not create database file when running on another desktop.

Please help me out. Thanks